# AngularJS Validation for Number of Digits in Phone No Field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, phone-number

I need to put validations in 2 fields:

1. Phone No -- (a) should have 10 digits,

   (b) in format: `XXX-XXX-XXXX`,

   (c) should have an alert pop-window if (a) & (b) is not satisfied
2. Email -- should have validations and alert pop for (a) invalid email format (no text before/after "@", no text after ".", no text before "." but after "@")

Also only once all the fields have some input AND satisfy all validations, should it display all details ON clicking the SUBMIT button.

For now, even if a certain field does not satisfy a validation, all field' details are displayed on clicking SUBMIT button.

**I would advise all to try the code out, test output to understand exactly what my problem is:**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" required placeholder="Enter First Name" 
ng-model="firstname" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cannot leave blank')" 
oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
<br>

<input type="search" required placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="lastname" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Cannot leave blank')" 
oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
<br>

<input type="text" required placeholder="Enter 10 digit no" ng-minlength="10" 
ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="phone" />

<input type="email" required placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" />
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
      Not valid email!</span>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()">
<br>
<div ng-show="x">

  <div>
    First Name: {{fname}}
  </div>

  <div>
    Last Name: {{lname}}
  </div>

  <div>
    Phone No: {{phno}}
  </div>

  <div>
    Email: {{em}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS SCRIPT:**

```
(function() {

  // Module(No Global Namespace)
  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var MainController = function($scope) {

    $scope.Search = function() {
      $scope.fname = $scope.firstname;
      $scope.lname = $scope.lastname;
      $scope.phno = $scope.phone;
      $scope.em = $scope.email;
    };



    phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (phone.length != 10) {
      alert("not 10 digits");
    } else {
      alert("yep, its 10 digits");
    }

    if ($scope.phone && $scope.firstname && $scope.lastname && $scope.email) {
      $scope.x = true;
    }


  };
  app.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```